# Display a text after product short description for specific product attribute in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to have it so for specific product attribute that contain "agave" text is displayed in the short description.

I have tried a few snippets of code but none seem to work. I have no problem getting them to work with Categories but I just want it for certain attributes of the products - Agave

```
function filter_woocommerce_short_description( $post_excerpt ) {
    global $post;

    if ( has_term( "agave", "categories", $post->ID ) ) {
        $post_excerpt .= "<br/>" . "Text Here";
    }
    return $post_excerpt; 
};

add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', 'filter_woocommerce_short_description',10, 1  );
```

I expect the text to show up under the certain attributes (Agave) but they do not

I have tried to use this

```
    add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', 
    'filter_woocommerce_short_description',10, 1  );
    function filter_woocommerce_short_description( $short_description ) {
     global $product;

   $string_values = $product->get_attribute('agave');

   if ( strpos($string_values, 'agave') !== false ) {
  $short_description .= '<br>' . __("Testing This Out - AGAVE");
    }
   return $short_description;
   }
```

Comment: Try changing 'categories' to 'product_cat'

Answer (score 1):

For a **specific product attribute** "agave" you will use something a bit different:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', 'filter_woocommerce_short_description',10, 1  );
function filter_woocommerce_short_description( $short_description ) {
    global $product;

    $string_values = $product->get_attribute('agave');

    if ( ! empty($string_values) ) {
        $short_description .= '<br>' . __("Text Here");
    }
    return $short_description;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Now if "agave" is a term  of a product attribute, you should need to set the product attribute name in `$product->get_attribute('attribute-name');`
and replace the condition by something like:

```
if ( strpos($string_values, 'agave') !== false ) {
```

---

***Note:*** The taxonomy for product category is `product_cat`, but not `categories`…

Comment: I have edited my original post with the code I used that did not work. Thanks for all the help though

Answer (score 0):

```
 add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', 'filter_woocommerce_short_description',10, 1  );
 function filter_woocommerce_short_description( $short_description ) {
     global $product;

   $string_values = $product->get_attribute('agave');
   $agave = $attributes["agave"];
   if ( $agave ) {
        $short_description .= '<br>' . __("Testing This Out - AGAVE");
    }
   return $short_description;
   }
```